# modify urls adding a css id at the end

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying modify some urls (on a wordpress website) by adding a css ID at the end:

So for ex: www.mywebsite.com/test/**?pa_gender=male**

should become: www.mywebsite.com/test/**?pa_gender=male#mycustomid**

Basically what im looking for is all urls that start with:

```
/test/?pa_(.*)$
```

to get a css id at the end like this:

```
/test/?pa_(.*)$1#mycustomid
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I guess it should be possible doing this with a custom php function?

Comment: this `#mycustomid` will be different for all pages or same? you can use .htaccess  if they remain same

Comment: you can't use one same id for different urls. Its css rule.

Comment: Still unclear what your question is. Need to know more about your scenario. Can you give some example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @friedemann_bach I have woocommerce shop (event) page using woocommerce products filter and essential grid. Since the product + filtering section starts at the middle of the page i use a #mycustomid in order to scroll to this section. When using a filter the page reloads (scrolling back to top) so I want to modify the search url by adding the #mycustomid

Comment: Judging by the sounds of it - you might need to attach Javascript to the page to pull out the custom id from the url and attach your own scroll event to scroll to that position once the filtering is done.